# Relation in Json-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, json-server

I want to create a database using **"json-server"** and I also used the **"relation"** topic, but I can't get the products of the user's shopping cart? Where is the problem? Thank you for helping me.

My "db.json" file example is as follows:

```
{
  "products": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" },
    { "id": 2, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "user-1",
      "cart": [
        { "id": 1, "productId": 1 },
        { "id": 2, "productId": 2 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And my example "URL" is as follows:
`http://localhost:5000/users?_expand=product`

i wanna to tried get products in user's cart, and i couldn't get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"json-server": "^0.17.0"*

The `_expand` and `_embed` will look up the foreign key on the top-level JSON object, not the nested object.

When you try to access `/users?_expand=product` resource, `json-server` will use [`expand()`](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/blob/26b52b97b13d2f0dccd6f92dc3772fabbfc2f5c8/src/server/router/plural.js#L31) function to handle the `?_expand=product` URL parameter.

```js
function expand(resource, e) {
  e &&
    [].concat(e).forEach((innerResource) => {
      const plural = pluralize(innerResource)
      if (db.get(plural).value()) {
        const prop = `${innerResource}${opts.foreignKeySuffix}`
        resource[innerResource] = db
          .get(plural)
          .getById(resource[prop])
          .value()
      }
    })
}
```

`resource` is:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "user-1",
  cart: [
    {
      id: 1,
      productId: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      productId: 2,
    },
  ],
}
```

`e` is `'product'`, `plural` is `'products'`, `prop` is `productId`

First, it will check if there are `products` data in the database using `db.get(plural).value()`.

The `resource[innerResource] = db.get(plural).getById(resource[prop]).value()` statement is the key. It will try to populate the `product` field with the product data get from the database by `productId`(get the value from the `resource` object). When it executes, it will be:

```js
resource['product'] = db.get('products').getById(resource['productId']).value()
```

As you can see, there is no `'productId'` field on the `resource` object.  That's why `json-server` can't expand or embed data for nested objects.

So, we have to adjust the data structure in the database to below:

`db.json`:

```json
{
    "products": [
        { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" },
        { "id": 2, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
    ],
    "users": [
        { "id": 1, "name": "user-1" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "user-2" }
    ],
    "cart": [
        { "id": 1, "productId": 1, "userId": 1 },
        { "id": 2, "productId": 2, "userId": 1 },
        { "id": 3, "productId": 1, "userId": 2 }
    ]
}
```

Start the JSON server:

```
npx json-server db.json

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/products
  http://localhost:3000/users
  http://localhost:3000/cart

  Home
  http://localhost:3000
```

`http://localhost:3000/user/1/cart?_expand=product&_expand=user`:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "productId": 1,
        "userId": 1,
        "product": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "json-server",
            "author": "typicode"
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "user-1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "productId": 2,
        "userId": 1,
        "product": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "json-server",
            "author": "typicode"
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "user-1"
        }
    }
]
```

`http://localhost:3000/user/2/cart?_expand=product&_expand=user`:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "productId": 1,
        "userId": 2,
        "product": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "json-server",
            "author": "typicode"
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "user-2"
        }
    }
]
```

`http://localhost:3000/users/?_embed=cart`:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "user-1",
        "cart": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "productId": 1,
                "userId": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "productId": 2,
                "userId": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "user-2",
        "cart": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "productId": 1,
                "userId": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```